# How to redirect to thank you page in Vue3.js

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, vuejs3

How can I create a redirect to another page on Vue?

Below I would like to insert a redirect after user login.

```
async function normalLoginClicked() {
  if(agreePrivacyPolicy.value) {
    ps_loading_dialog.value.openModal();

    await userProvider.loginWithEmailId(email.value, password.value);        
                
    ps_loading_dialog.value.closeModal();
    if (userProvider.userResource.status == PsStatus.SUCCESS) {
      redirect();           
    }
}
        

function redirect() {
  userProvider.navigateUserLoginRedirect(route.query.redirect, 'dashboard', router, route.query.redirect, route.query, route.params);
}
```

Comment: Can you indicate where did you find the snippet in you redirect function? That would help us to understand what you really want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to move on a client-side context is to use the following after your `await`

```js
router.push('/my-cool/path-redirection')
```

As explained here: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#navigate-to-a-different-location